# Unable to fetch authorization code from Summer 15 Org

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, summer-15

1. Created a connected app on the hub org
2. In the connected app Enabled OAuth Settings
3. Provided full access and Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access) oauth scope.
4. provided a callback URL to a vf page
5. Performed authoratization to get the summer 15 org authorization code.
6. Pop up came to enter the target org's username and password.
7. once entered , The connected app requested permission.
8. Click allow. Instead of redirecting to the source org it tried to access the the redirect page on the target org.
9. This issue appears when the target org is on summer 15. It worked fine with spring 15

Comment: Are the source and target orgs on the same instance, perhaps?

Comment: If source and target are on Summer 15 it does not work. While when source and target are on spring 15 it works

Comment: But are the instances the same - both na15.salesforce.com, for example, or different - e.g. na15.salesforce.com and na24.salesforce.com?

Comment: this issue comes when my target org is summer 15 org. I am facing this issue when I use generic callback url . For eg - https://login.salesforce.com/apex/vfpage_name. It works fine when I use instance name. For eg:- https://na24.visual.force.com/apex/vfpage_name. where na24 is my source org instance

Comment: na24 is your source org instance; what is your target org instance?

Comment: eu5 is my target org instance. But as I said earlier its not specific to an instance . It is happening with summer 15 as target

Answer (score 0):

You should use My Domain to provide a consistent domain name for your VF callback, like `https://companyname.my.salesforce.com/apex/vfpage_name`. To be honest, I'm surprised it ever worked at all using `login.salesforce.com`, since Salesforce will use whatever session is active session in deciding where to actually send the browser. This seems to be what's happening in Summer '15. I can't explain why it used to work.