# Unable to connect to org with same instance using OAuthConnection

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

1. Create a connected app
2. Add the callback URL to that connected app as the URL of a VF page. For Eg - 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/mypage'.
3. Connect to another salesforce org of the same instance.Énter the login details ie username and password
4. Allow permission to the connected app create on your source org to access info about target org by clicking on Állow Button'
5. Instead of redirecting back to source org it redirects me to the target org and tries to open up the page mentioned in the callback url.
6. This issue is coming when my source and target org are on same instance. It works fine when source and target instances are different.

Comment: I am not vouching 100% but looks like salesforce is picking the latest active session and pushing you to the target org since both orgs are on the same instance.

Comment: Yes. But due to this it is breaking the app. Earlier when source and target  orgs were on same instance on performing oauth it used to ask for login twice. First with target org credentials and then with source org credentials. Now it just logs into the target org without asking for source org credentials

Comment: Did you try using custom domain as recommended bymetadaddy? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79046/unable-to-fetch-authorization-code-from-summer-15-org

Comment: The app can run on custom domain as well as normal salesforce instance. Thus, cannot restrict it for custom domain